# Why is not bootstrap carousel content fixed positioned with respect to body?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

Here is an example where the image inside bootstrap carousel is fixed positioned with `top: 0`. But the image is not fixed with respect to the body:

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  I am dummy content <br>
  I am dummy content <br>
  I am dummy content <br>
  I am dummy content <br>
  I am dummy content <br>
  I am dummy content <br>
</div>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Chania"/>
        <br/>
        <br>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/><br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>   
  </div> 
</div>
```

My question is why doesn't the image get positioned with respect to the body?

Comment: Can you show a real example? Inside the snippet I don’t see any carousel functionality. And could you also describe what you are trying to achieve here? Because positioning a single image that is part of a carousel fixed doesn’t seem to make that much sense to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe I have intentionally removed carousel sliding. What I want to achieve here is to put the image inside bootstrap carousel at the the top of screen. But even applying fixed position to the images this doesn't happen.

Comment: I believe the class `carousel-inner` is picked up by bootstrap and given position relative, and so the image css rule references from the div containing that class.

Comment: @PhilS Isn't relative positioning always with respect to the body irrespective of parent's positioning?

Comment: No, relative is relative to the flow of the document, (unless a parent of it has a more specific effect), once you give a parent element a relative position, fixed and absolute use that as it's base position.

Comment: @PhilS Do you have any reference to back up your claim. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values) suggest the opposite; _position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport.._

Comment: Seems like it is because of `transform` property. MDN says: _When an ancestor has the transform property set to something different from none then this ancestor is used as container instead of the viewport_

Comment: I don't, that's a useful bit information, I've always treated fixed to be equivalent to absolute, so it seems I'm incorrect there, sorry about that, you learn something new each day.

Comment: @PhilS No issues, Thanks for trying to help : )